# Kotlin delegation, what should I test?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mutation-testing, pitest

In Kotlin the powerful construct of delegation can be used to extend functionality of existing interfaces by reusing existing implementations.

```
class Demo : Map by HashMap {}
```

Questions:

- What should I be testing? Testing hashmap from the example is not the target of this test. It seems very verbose to verify the complete implementation, I would rather like to verify that the delegation of the proper fields take place.
- When using mutation testing, e.g. using [PItest](http://pitest.org), how do I catch all mutations? The report shows quite a few mutations, correctly I believe. The Kotlin compiler creates byte code for all delegations.

Comment: Why would you want to test the delegation? It is not your responsibility to test the Kotlin compiler

Comment: I agree that it is not my responsibility to test the kotlin compiler. But it is to test my class. I would like to know how to do that without testing the kotlin compiler or the HashMap.

Comment: Is your `Demo` class actually a `Map`? Then I guess you'd have to test all `HashMap` functionality in the context of your class. If you figure out a way to use composition instead of inheritance in this use case you'd hopefully have a lot less code to test.

Comment: The test ability improves when I use `class Demo(map: Map = HashMap()): Map by map {}`. Then I can mock the map.

Comment: Testing whether the delegate is transparent is detailed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225663/checking-in-a-unit-test-whether-all-methods-are-delegated